# Which version is better and why: `fn(a: AType)` or fn<T extends AType>(a: T)`?

Tags: typescript

```
interface OwnsSth {
  sth: number
}

function a<T extends OwnsSth>(a1: T) {
  console.log(a1.sth)
}

function b(b1: OwnsSth) {
  console.log(b1.sth)
}

const foo = {
  sth: 2,
  sthElse: 'hooo,hooo'
}

a(foo);
b(foo);
```

This code works correcty. I know why it works, but I can't say which and why version (a or b) of function is better.

Answer (score 1):

If the type parameter appears only once in your parameter list, you can safely use version B.

```
function b(b1: OwnsSth);
```

Otherwise, you will need type parameters. For example...

```
function getProperty<T extends object>(obj: T, prop: keyof T) {
  return obj[prop];
}
```

As you can see, `T` appears twice in the parameter list.